# 3D Surface plot and Scatter plot in Flask - Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

Can we combine two 3D plots - Scatter 3D and Surface 3D in bokeh which share the same columnDataSource on the same 3D axes?

My objective is to show some 3D moving points (like a path which starts from one point and ends at another point) on a 3D static Surface plot in Flask using bokeh. I need to plot something like this https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/surface3d but I do not want to move the whole surface, I just want to move few points on this surface(like a path traced)

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The example you linked uses visjs. As far as I can tell, it does not support both scatter 3d and surface 3d on the same plot. You could use a different library, such as plotly.JS if you like which does work.